# Format cells in excel to add multiple decimals

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a 10 digit tariff code and a customer requires it to be formatted with decimals ie:  6212.90.00.30  There are hundreds on the list.  I would like to format the cells to do this automatically.  I have tried going to FORMAT CELLS, NUMBER TAB, CUSTOM and in the TYPE bar I have put ####.##.##,    This put 3 decimals at the end of my 10 digit number.  Please let me know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
0000\.00\.00\.00
```

One needs to escape the `.` with `\`.  This basically turns the special `.` into text.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found another method, using substring and concatenation.

I tried a lot but could not succeed, because editor converts every thing what I post, in its own ways, making answer very very clumsy, which is very difficult to understand by you.

I copied the Excel Portion, which was self explanatory, but then Editor says ONLY IMAGE not allowed.

I converted everything to Word Table, and along with comments I sent. But I myself was confused to read it again.

I shall send you only explanation, when time permits.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1... Say, your given 10 digit number is in Column A.............
Step 2... Answer you get from Column B...................
Step 3... For that, first prepare Column C...... for first four digits,  D.............. for digits 5 and 6,............. E for 7th and 8th,.......... F for 9th and 10th difits.
Step 4... The formulae in the Cell C2 is............. C2=Left(A2,4)...........
Step 5... D2= MID(A2,5,2)..............
Step 6... E2= MID(A2,7,2 )....................
Step 7... F2= RIGHT (A2,2) ........................
Step 8... Copy the Rormula Range, C2:F2 down the rows..........
Step 9... Now to get answer column B ................Enter Formula  : ............
......B2 = C2&"."&D2&"."&E2&"."&F2...............
Step 10... Copy B2 down the row................
Step 11... If you want, you can hide the columns C, D, E, and F.....................
Step 12... Using such method, any format can be achieved...................

Note : As Editor is Mixing All Line Statements in One Line the legibility is highly affected. So I have to play with many dots, citing steps.

I am new in answering, and totally don't know how to type answers......
I feel very guilty, but all of you please bear with me till I get the knowledge of How to Answer.....THANKS.